# How to custom a hint in simple_form?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, simple-form

I have in my simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :password,
                      required: true,
                      hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                      input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
```

I succeeded to get my form labels white. But my hint remains grey. Its color has been automatically assigned by Bootstrap:

```
/* line 52, node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/_text.scss */
.text-muted {
  /*! color: #6c757d !important; */
}
```

How can I turn this text white?
Thanks.

Comment: Write a more specific selector than the one currently applying!? If you need to overwrite `.text-muted { color: whatever !important}`, using the same specificty and placing your CSS after `bootstrap.css` will work. If you don't want to worry about order and you want yours to apply even if it's parsed sooner, use `.text-muted.text-muted { color: white !important }`. Either scope it or prefix it with a parent selector if you don't want all the `.text-muted` in your app to become white.

Comment: I get it thank you the hint ! I found the right path on the debugger  small.form-text.text-muted {color: white; } and easily succeeds :)